# How to check MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE for my session

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I need help for gettng the TKProf of a sql query.
The oracle [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/sqltrace.htm#i4183) says to check the following parameters before enabling SQL trace.

```
TIMED_STATISTICS, MAX_DUMP_FILE_SIZE, and USER_DUMP_DEST
```

Can someone help me how to check their value for current session, and how to set them if the are incorrect?

I tried

```
show parameter max_dump;

show parameter timed_statistics;
```

from sqlplus (windows), but i get the ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error.

Also, any further help on the further steps of TKPROF will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant select on `v_$parameter`

```
SQL> show parameter max_dump
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant select on v_$parameter to hr;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn hr/hr
Connected.
SQL> show parameter max_dump

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ---------
max_dump_file_size                   string      unlimited
SQL>
```

Comment: I dont have the sysdba credentials, and I dont have the DBA around. Is there any other way I can check/modify there parameters for my session?

Comment: I don't think it is possible without this view.